# How to use same TestFlight invitation from different devices?

Tags: ios-appstore

I want to test beta app with different devices, but when I open app from mail in TestFlight and try to start it refuse and shows "The invite has already been used". Any workaround?

[image]

Comment: You should just be able to log into the same account on both TestFlight apps. The apps should appear.

Comment: Open Testflight.app on the second device. Connect-it to the same account as the one in the invitation. You should be able to download the app.

Comment: revoked and invited myself again from beta testing, this is how it works

Answer (score 6):

As Janos said, 
In order to get an invitation code again, the hack is to remove that email account from being a tester and re-add him again.
Apple will send him an email **with a new redeem code**.

Otherwise, Apple will send an email **without a redeem code**.

Comment: Really hate that Apple can't make something like testing on multiple devices easy. Such an obvious thing and it's not even clearly documented how to do it or, if it is problematic, why they wouldn't make it possible.